# Is there a recommended way to implement a multi-step wizard in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

TYPO3 is kind of new to me, but what I try (need) to implement is a multi-step wizard without a form, just a few buttons which lead to other buttons which then lead to specific pages. It should contain a back button and a step-indicator.

I first started to use html with vanilla JS but since the Wizard should support multi language I am a bit confused. Could it be better done with a own Extension? Use the Controller with Fluid?

Can you give me any tips on how I could tackle the problem in a good, TYPO3 manner way?

I tried it with vanilla JS and many if-else conditions. If button1 was clicked, set its style to none; and set the style of button2 to block; etc.

I tried it with a controller passing all the wizard data to the view, use fluid to iterate and generate buttons.

But nothing seems to be a *good* solution. It all ends up with a bunch of DRY and hacky code.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much sounds like a "tab" element to me. You could go for the official introduction package or maybe the bootstrap package, that is the base for the introduction package.

https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/introduction
https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/bootstrap_package

With these packages as a base, you could easily implement something like this:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#javascript-behavior

Answer (score 0):

As you want that wizard in front end it is no specific TYPO3 problem.

There are elements in TYPO3 which are called 'wizard'. But that are forms to get some information to fill in a normal back end form field. That has nothing to do with the front end and the wizard you want.

For your solution it is necessary to analyse your requirements.

First: is the decision tree fix or may it vary sometime?
Second: how many decision levels do you have? how many endpoints do you have?

A small fix tree can be hardcoded.

If you expect changes or have lot of levels it might be better to have a flexible solution which gets called recursively.

This might include a hierarchical data structure to represent the decisions until you get an end point with an url to the final page.

The answer to the question about the amount of decisions might change the implementation:
If you only have a few decisions all data might be stored in the initial page and javascript only changes visibility or content of elements.

If you have a lot of data you might consider AJAX to get only small parts of data for the next decision from the server. repeating until you reach an end point with a final url.

In general:
have a data structure with something like:

```
ID
title/question
option1-text 
option1-url / next node-ID
option2-text
option2-url / next node-ID
:
```